# JnrpeClient : java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io, nrpe, jnrpe

The nrpe agent is working just fine but when executing this code above i still getting this error: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

```
 try {
        JNRPEClient client = new JNRPEClient("192.168.121.129", 5666, false);
        client.setTimeout(30);
        ReturnValue ret = client.sendCommand("check_ping -H 192.168.121.129 -t 60 -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5");
        System.out.println(ret.getMessage());
        System.exit(ret.getStatus().intValue());
    } catch (JNRPEClientException exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getCause());
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor parameter to true to enable SSL and that should fix
your issue.

```
JNRPEClient client = new JNRPEClient("192.168.121.129", 5666, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, did you configure ssl on the nrpe host client?

Comment: I didn't configure the SSL on nrpe.

Comment: Please add your IP address to allowed_hosts in nrpe.cfg

Comment: It's working with the dev version. But still, they didn't release it. You can locally build and can try it.

Comment: Can you please send me a tutorial or some hints to follow

Comment: Are you using a maven project?